# app quits in iphone 4

Tags: iphone

i am using this , but if i start my app again on iphone 4 then it quits ,
problem is it dont know indexpath.row , now how to solve this isuee??/

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
int j=indexPath.row;
    if(j==0)
    {
        UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_jurong.png"];
        UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];

        [bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 13, 30, 30)];

        //Finally give this imageView to the cell

        [cell.contentView addSubview:bgImageView];
        [bgImage release];

    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the output of the debugger or any crash reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[bgImage release];` write `[bgImageView release];`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be releasing bgImage. It is already autoreleased.